Gerschgorin Circle Theorem and ordering of eigenvalues
Suppose $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n*n}$ is diagonal and $E\in \mathbb{R^{n*n}}$ be any matrix. Use Gerschgorin circle theorem to show that if $||E||_{\infty}<min_{i\neq j}|\frac{d_{ii}-d_{jj}}{2}|$ then there exists an ordering of eigenvalues of $D+E$, $\mu_{1},\mu_{2},\ldots ,\mu_{n}$ such that $|d_{ii}-\mu_{i}|<||E||_{\infty}$ for all $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n$
I applied the circle theorem and concluded that there exists an $i$ and eigenvalue $\mu_{i}
$ of $D+E$ such that $|d_{ii}-\mu_{i}|<||E||_{\infty}$.To show that there exists an ordering of eigenvalues this way I tried to show that for no two eigenvalues of $D+E$, $|d_{ii}-\mu_{i}|<||E||_{\infty}$ and $|d_{ii}-\mu_{j}|<||E||_{\infty}$ hold for different $i$ and $j$. To do that I tried to obtain a contradiction and wrote $|\mu_{i}-\mu_{j}|<min_{i\neq j}|d_{ii}-d_{jj}|$. Then how to make porogress? I need help. My final try was trying to compare eigenvalues of $D+E$ and $D$ when $D$ is diagonal but I could not find a general rule that links them

For each $i$, consider the open disc $D_i$ centred on $d_{ii}$ of radius $| E |{\infty}$. By assumption on $|E|{\infty}$, those discs are pairwise disjoint. So if you could prove that for every $i$, the disc $D_i$ contains exactly one eigenvalue of $D+ E$ (i.e. that there is exactly one eigenvalue $\mu$ of $D+E$ such that $|d_{ii} - \mu| < |E|_{\infty}$), then you could label $\mu_i$ this unique eigenvalue. This would mean that there is only one possible ordering.  (One shouldn't expect that $|\mu_i - \mu_j| < |d_{ii}-d_{jj}|$ since perhaps $\mu_i < d_{ii} < d_{jj} < \mu_j$.)

What if in your last statement they are between dii and djj?

Of course they could be between, but the point is that they might not be. For instance, take $D = \mathrm{diag}(1, 2)$ and $E = \mathrm{diag}(-1/3, 1/3)$, so that $D+E = \mathrm{diag}(2/3, 7/3)$. Hence you won't be able to prove that $|\mu_i - \mu_j| < |d_{ii} - d_{jj}|$ because this inequality does sometimes fail in the context of your question.

I am not trying to prove but trying to obtain a contradiction by assuming two points can be inside.

Sorry, I had missed that you were aiming for a contradiction. But then, simply flip my argument upside down: it is possible that $d_{ii} < \mu_i < \mu_j < d_{jj}$, e.g. take $D = \mathrm{diag}(1,2)$ and $E = \mathrm{diag}(1/3, -1/3)$ so that $D+E = \mathrm{diag}(4/3, 5/3)$, so you shouldn't expect to reach a contradiction in this way.

To expand on my first hint: using Gershgorin theorem, one can prove that every eigenvalue $\mu$ of $D+E$ satisfies $|\mu - d_{ii}| \le |E|_{\infty}$ for at least one $i$. (Equality is possible here, as shown by the explicit examples I gave in my other comments.) To prove that for each $\mu$ there is at most one such $i$, one can invoke the continuity of eigenvalues (for the family $t \mapsto D + tE$).
